# Error: redefinition of group name 'pk' as group 2; was group 1 at position 38

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Using Django Rest Framework, I am creating endpoints for **doctor** model in my app `app_api` using `ModelViewSet`. I am encountering the following error on adding an extra action for updating the `is_verified` field with `verify` method having `@action` decorator.

> ```
> error at /app_api/viewset/doctor/6/
> redefinition of group name 'pk' as group 2; was group 1 at position 38
> ```

Please find the code below.

**urls.py**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('doctor', views.DoctorViewSet, basename='doctor')

urlpatterns = [
    path('viewset/', include(router.urls)),
    path('viewset/<int:pk>', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**model.py**

```
# Doctor Model
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')    
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
```

**serializer.py**

```
# Doctor Model Serializer
class DoctorModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('is_verified',)

# Doctor Partial Update Model Serializer
class DoctorUpdateVerifyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Doctor        
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'is_verified')
        read_only_fields = ('name',)
```

**views.py**

```
class DoctorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = DoctorModelSerializer
    queryset = Doctor.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        serializer_class = self.serializer_class
        if self.request.method == 'PATCH' and self.action == 'verify':
            serializer_class = DoctorUpdateVerifyModelSerializer
        return serializer_class

    @action(methods=['patch'], detail=True)    
    def verify(self, request, pk=None):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(self.get_object(), data=request.data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Now when I am adding an extra action for routing the method `verify` with the `@action` decorator, I am getting the following error on accessing url for ***/app_api/viewset/doctor/6/*** and ***/app_api/viewset/doctor/6/verify/*** where `6` is the primary key of `doctor`

> ```
> error at /app_api/viewset/doctor/6/
> redefinition of group name 'pk' as group 2; was group 1 at position 38
> ```

If I remove the `detail=True` from the `verify` method annotated with `@action`, it works well for ***/app_api/viewset/doctor/6/***. My question is why this error is generated if I have `@action` decorator with `detail=True`.

Comment: Why do you include your router urls twice in your urls.py? Have you tried removing the second inclusion?

Comment: Questions seeking help debugging should include the full traceback. Only the error message by itself is not very informative.

Answer (score 2):

this type of error comes when someone pass id parameter with same name as I did in my code(pic).So always try to avoid by passing same name as id in url parameter[image]
.

Try like this by diff-diff name.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by removing the second inclusion of `router.urls` i.e., `path('viewset/<int:pk>', include(router.urls))`, from the `urls.py`.

The updated code of **urls.py** is

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('doctor', views.DoctorViewSet, basename='doctor')

urlpatterns = [
    path('viewset/', include(router.urls)),
]
```